# running script in current directory on diffrent directory

Tags: bash

I run a script which compresses certain files and rename them.
I don't want to copy it to each directory and operate it from inside

how can I run it from outside the target directory to act on it, tried

**'bash compress.sh target_dir/'**

Comment: you should use command linr arguments and add a logic inside your script to compress the directory which is being passed as argument

Comment: Surely you can do`cd /path/to/data && bash /path/to/script`

Comment: You did not show the content of `compress.sh`, but you don't need to have your working directory set in a particular way to compress or move a file. Also, running a program does not require that the program is stored in your working directory.

Comment: That is exactly the question, how to run it on a directory that does not contain it?

Comment: See my comment above which shows how to do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

In a bash script you can use input via $1 for the first input ($2 for second,..). You could write your script such that it is working with this. Easiest way might be to store pwd

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
baseDir=$PWD
cd "$1" || echo 'Check input'; exit 1
# ..your stuff..
cd "$baseDir" || :
```

To do this for all sub directories you can use find and a loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
baseDir=$PWD # or any other path
allSubDirectories=$(find "$baseDir" -type d)
for d in $allSubDirectories
do
  cd "$d" || :
  # ..your stuff..
  cd "$baseDir" || :
done
```

Comment: Miro, it is preferred to use the `$PWD` environment variable rather than the `pwd` command. Also use `$(command)` rather than back-ticks. Also, after `cd` commands that can fail, it is advised to place a conditional statement like `cd "$PWD" || exit 1` if you want to terminate the script if it cannot change directory. or `cd "$PWD" || :` followed by null command `:`, to ignore the failure to `cd` if you are very there you have no failure case to handle in your script.

Comment: Miro, there are other issues with your  answer's code. You would get all problem highlighted and explained if you paste your code to the shell's static analysis tools https://shellcheck.net/.